# Search cell for matching value then copy

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to filter my Excel table with VBA code.

A1, B1, C1 are titles

- Column A = All (A2: xx)
- Column B = Search Content`s (B2: xx)
- Column C = (C2: xx)

Everything in column B should be searched for column A and if one or more is found then column C should be written.

I tried the following.

```
Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A2:A2000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:B2000"), CopyToRange:=Range("C2:C2000")
```

So that everything in column A is copied to column C but not to be compared to column B.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Put your data here and show output.

Comment: Hello @Harun24HR Thank you for your Interest. I have uploaded my Excel file with simple data to [link](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13447806/ServerBackup.xlsx.html) Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Did you like the Collection solution I suggested? If so, please mark it as your answer.

Comment: Hi dbmtr...did any of the solutions work for you? I'd like to know which solutions work best for people. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a helping column, then you can easily do that without `VBA` coding.

Helping column formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$9,0)),ROW(),"")
```

Then use following formula to extract not backuped servers list.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$31,SMALL($D$2:$D$31,ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[See the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FSAkwALsv1aJDY862CxkhzZIQwBWuwSX/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info.
I have to realize with VBA and with this formula I do not have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Title.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rngCria As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = Sheets("Tabelle2")

    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1:a2000")
        Set rngCria = .Range("B1", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rngTo = .Range("c1")
    End With
    rngDB.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCria, rngTo


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListMatches()
    Dim rngColumnA As Range, celColumnB As Range, rngColumnB As Range
    Set rngColumnA = Range("A2:A" & Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rngColumnB = Range("B2:B" & Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each celColumnB In rngColumnB
        If Not rngColumnA.Find(What:=celColumnB) Is Nothing Then Range("C" & Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = celColumnB.Value
    Next celColumnB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using A Collection might be even faster in your application:

```
Sub ListMatches()
    Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R As Range, Nc As New Collection
    Set R1 = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set R2 = Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each R In R1
        Nc.Add R.Value, R.Value
    Next R
    For Each R In R2
        Err = 0
        Nc.Add R.Value, R.Value, 1
        If Err = 0 Then
            Range("C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = R.Value
            Nc.Remove 1
        End If
    Next R
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```